# installing java using chef solo on ec2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am trying my first recipe with chef-solo - a simple recipe that is trying to install java before doing anything. I want to install Oracle version of java, but I have come across multiple failure messages. How do I fix this? Here's my configuration -

```
 sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json
```

My solo.rb looks like this

```
cookbook_path "/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks"
```

and web.json

```
{
    "java": {
        "jdk_version": "7",
        "java_home": "opt/java",
        "oracle" : {
            "accept_oracle_download_terms": true
        }
    },
    "run_list" :  [ "recipe[testapp]" ]
}
```

My testapp recipe default.rb

```
include_recipe "java::default"
```

I've specified java as dependency in metadata.rb. This is what I get when I run the above on a fresh ec2 node.

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] WARN: Using java::default instead is recommended.
Converging 7 resources
Recipe: java::openjdk
  * package[openjdk-7-jdk] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[openjdk-7-jdk]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
---- End output of apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 ----
Ran apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 returned 100


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks/java/recipes/openjdk.rb

 46:   package pkg do
 47:     version node['java']['openjdk_version'] if node['java']['openjdk_version']
 48:   end
 49: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks/java/recipes/openjdk.rb:46:in `block in from_file'

package("openjdk-7-jdk") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "openjdk-7-jdk"
  version "7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2"
  cookbook_name :java
  recipe_name "openjdk"
end



[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ubuntu/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] ERROR: package[openjdk-7-jdk] (java::openjdk line 46) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
---- End output of apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 ----
Ran apt-get -q -y install openjdk-7-jdk=7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 returned 100
[2015-05-08T20:50:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Try including the "apt" cookbook on your runlist. This will perform a "apt-get update" command This normally solves most package install issues on a new server.

Comment: I manually did an apt-get update before running chef-solo. It didn't change anything.

Comment: in the error it says `STDERR: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo dpkg --configure -a did it.

Comment: You should explain why that "did it".

Comment: coz, this is what it does - Reconfigure an unpacked package. If -a  or  --pending  is  given
              instead  of  package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are
              configured.

              Configuring consists of the following steps:

              1. Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back  up  the  old
              conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

              2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.